# Rails - Execute actions on post's index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I have a model "Products" (which is a child model of parent model "Assortments") which can be liked by the user. Right now, you can only like the Product on the Products Show page because i'm able to find the products ID, which is what i need to like it

```
def like
  @assortment = Assortment.find(params[:assortment_id])
  begin
    current_user.vote_for(@product = Product.find(params[:id]))
    respond_with @product, :location => assortment_product_path
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    redirect_to @product
  end
end
```

I would also like user's to be able to like the product on the products index page. For example, if you go to Pinterest, you can like all the products on their fluid grid layout page as well as on each pictures respective page.

This is one of those things I have yet to learn how to do with Rails. How can i accomplish this??

Thanks in advance! Happy Holidays

Comment: Exactly the same. Put the `id` in the button on the `index` view. Something like `button_to 'Like', "products/like/#{product.id}"`

Comment: Oh lord if that's true then I should just quit dev lol

Comment: but the `product_link_path(id: product.id)` below is slightly more correct than the `"#{string surgery}"` version. C-;

Comment: @Phlip: Much prettier, more maintainable, but equally correct. But yeah, I've been away from Rails for a while now, I don't know all the neat stuff. Which is why I'm writing comments, not answers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `like` action is in your `ProductsController`, and you have set `@products` equal to the products you want for your index page, and you're using erb, put something like this in your view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to "Like", product_link_path(id: product.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Even if you have it set up differently, it can't be too far off from this.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest `method: :post` or `button_to`; as "like" presumably changes the state of the server, it would violate the GET contract.

Comment: Yeah, he didn't specify what kind of action this was. OP, you'll have to pass `method: *verb*` to the args of `product_link_path` as necessary. If it's a `GET`, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: If it's a GET, it's wrong. GET requests should never change the state of the server, and I'm pretty sure "liking" something would do so.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered! I got it working and learned something new.

Comment: @Amadan he's not modifying the `products` resource though. He's creating a `Like` (I think?). If it's just a column on the product, it should be handled in the `update` action. If a `Like` is a separate model, this request should be hitting the `LikesController`

Comment: @Kaleidoscope: Doesn't matter what controller he's hitting, I was saying that as soon as *anything* on the server changes (excluding the transparent stuff like logging or stats), the request must not be GET. For example, Google bot could (and probably would) like all the publicly accessible pages if they are GET links, unless specifically told not to. Justin, good on you :)